# Prove that in a ring with at least two elements $0\neq 1$.

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing

Let R be a non-trivial ring then prove $0\neq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume, to the contrary, that 1 = 0. Since $R$ is a non-trivial ring, there is an element
$a\in  ~R$ such that $a\neq0$. However, then $a=a·1=a·0=0,$
which is a contradiction.

Hence $1\neq0.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show by considering $x(0+0)$ that $x\cdot 0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

An element $y$ which has both $0$- and $1$-element properties, leaves no room for other elements in the ring $R$. For an arbitrary $x \in R$ one has
$$
x =^1 x y =^0 x (y+y)=^D xy + xy =^1 x + x \Rightarrow x = 0
$$
The uniqueness of the $0$ element would give that $R = \{ 0 \}$.